# Proper grounding of old fuse panel now turned J-Box

Tags: electrical, grounding, junction-box, grounding-and-bonding

I am working on my old house from the early 1900s. It has 100A service, a 6x15A FUSE panel that was turned into a sub panel powered by 2x 20A circuits from a small "newer" 100A breaker panel. The breaker panel is a corroded,cobbled up mess and I want to upgrade it to new larger panel, turning the old fuse panel into J-box. There are all metal outlets and switch boxes with flexible metallic conduit back to the old fuse panel then 3/4 EMT back to the breaker box.  I have grounded all outlets using jumpers screwed to the metal outlet boxes. I have run 12g THHN for all 6 conductors and neutrals back to the breaker panel.

I am having an electrician hang the new panel but want to make certain it is done correctly.

1. How does the "new" J-box PROPERLY ground to the new breaker panel? The old neutrals will be connected directly, via THHN, to the new panel. (My feeble research says bare 8g bonded from metal j-box to new panel)
2. What is the maximum load I can run? (Assuming I have a 20A minisplit, regular A/C, Microwave, Fridge, electric dryer, and Electric stove....is that too much load for my service? If necessary I CAN use gas for stove/range and possibly the dryer.)

EDIT:The house has 100A panel now. I am preparing to sell in the spring. I am not wanting to spend the >$5,500 to completely upgrade to 200A service. The lead to the house is only capable of 120A. I would have to completely re-mast and the whole ball of wax. Hence, it has been suggested to just put in a larger panel, leaving the main at 100A, and if new buyer wants more capacity, they can do it later or negotiate it into the purchase. I'm wondering how close I am to being over capacity.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please [merge your accounts](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you have access to edit, comment, and accept answers on your own question. Note that posting responses as answers can result in an [automated lock](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) that can prevent others from assisting you.

Comment: Flexible metal conduit is not considered a valid grounding method, except in very limited circumstances. So it appears your metal switch/outlet boxes are not in fact grounded, in spite of your jumpers. You need to add 12 AWG equipment grounds along with the THHN conductors. Your old fuse-box-converted-to-juction-box only requires the same grounding as any other metal box, and the EMT feeding it is sufficient for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

As far as maximum load, that depends on a **Load Calculation**. This takes into account:

- The size of your house (square feet)
- Certain required circuits (kitchen, bathroom, laundry)
- Cooking equipment (a bunch of special rules involved)
- HVAC
- Other large fixed loads such as water heater
- Large appliances such as clothes dryer

and puts it all together to come up with a single number. If that is less than 100A, you're doing great. If it is more than 100A then you need to do one or more of:

- Service upgrade
- Automatic load shedding
- Replace electric appliances with gas appliances

Your main panel is a little confusing. Is it a 100A panel that will still be a 100A panel? Or is that panel being replaced at the same time as the old fuse panel is turned into a junction box? If it is being replaced then I recommend a 200A panel in order to have more space for future expansion, ideally at least 30 breaker spaces, even if you don't need that many right now. This may also be the right time to just go ahead and do a heavy-up, since the hard part is replacing the old panels and your utility may very well already have 200A-capable wire from the street to your house already (they did in my case, and then replaced it anyway because "they always do").

Comment: In my case they upgraded me and put in a call to the utility to replace my street wires in that order. "It isn't _right_, but in free air the existing wires can shed enough heat that they can carry the extra wattage -- and your usage currently doesn't approach even 100 A. The alternative is waiting for the electric company to get around to doing this service, and they're pretty badly backlogged." Inspector agreed with them, so... Several years later, as far as I know, I'm still running on the same wires.